# How to make any integer positive in c++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I take 2 values a and b from user and perform a-b but if the answer of the user is -ve then i want to convert it into postive.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<(a-b);
    return 0;
}
```

How to do that ?

Comment: you can just check if the number is smaller than one and then set it to `a *= -1`

Comment: Take a look at [std::abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)

Comment: Your own description, "if the answer is negative then make it positive", is one possible solution. Have you not encountered `if` yet?

Comment: `cout<<((a>b)? (a-b):b-a);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to return only positive integers. The easiest way is to use [std::abs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)

```
cout << std::abs(a-b) << "\n";
```